# Combining Field Values in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose my variables are X and Y

The values of X are A, B, C

The values of Y are 1, 2, 3

There is also an ID field. The X and Y values are unique to each ID.

Using SAS, I want to create another variable that combines the values of X and Y with a period in between: A.1, B.2, C.3

How should I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CATX` function (or any CAT family function, really) will do it for you.

```
newfield = catx('.',x,y);
```